# Bootstrap datepicker datedisable not working on second ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

**Hi there,i got trouble in second ajax call doesn't change the value of datesdisabled of datepicker in below. is there a way to fix it ? Thanks**

```
$("#select_roomtype").on("change",function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:registerpost_url,
        type:"POST",
        headers:{'X-CSRF-Token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        data: {roomtype:$(this).val()},
        cache: false,           // To unable request pages to be cached
        success:function(data) {
            $("#sandbox-container .input-group").datepicker({
                format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
                autoclose: true,
                datesDisabled:data,
                startDate: today,
                endDate:endday,
                maxViewMode: 1
                });
            }
        });
});*
```

Comment: i think you need to destroy datepicker before create it twice

Comment: destroy it after date-picker worked?

Comment: before you create it again in success callback function

Comment: wow it worked man thanks a lot <3

Comment: u are life save :D

Comment: you are welcome